# Angular Testing of modal confirm dialog service Jest, Jasmine

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, modal-dialog, karma-jasmine

I have the following problem: I used the code from this site

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-confirmation-dialog

to implement a confirm dialog in my angular project.

Now I want to test the service:

**confirmation-dialog.service.ts**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { ConfirmationDialogComponent } from './confirmation-dialog.component';

@Injectable()
export class ConfirmationDialogService {

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) { }

  public confirm(
    title: string,
    message: string,
    btnOkText: string = 'OK',
    btnCancelText: string = 'Cancel',
    dialogSize: 'sm'|'lg' = 'sm'): Promise<boolean> {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ConfirmationDialogComponent, { size: dialogSize });
    modalRef.componentInstance.title = title;
    modalRef.componentInstance.message = message;
    modalRef.componentInstance.btnOkText = btnOkText;
    modalRef.componentInstance.btnCancelText = btnCancelText;

    return modalRef.result;
  }

}
```

My method to call it is this:

```
this.confirmationDialogService.confirm(confirmHeadline, confirmString)
    .then((confirmed) => { do stuff});
```

I read that I simply could do it with a spyOn method, like

`spyOn(ConfirmationDialogService, 'confirm').and.callFake ...`

But it doesn't take the second argument. I'm new to testing, so I hope somebody can help me... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use spyOn. And you can take more than the (method) second argument by using .withArgs(args) after. SpyOn typically looks like this

`spyOn(obj, 'method');`

But .withArgs(args) allows you to add more:

```js
spyOn( modalService, 'open').withArgs(alertDialog, params, ...);
```

You can [read more about spyOn here](https://jasmine.github.io/api/edge/global.html#spyOn)